# Posting FormData from Angular to Web API, data always null

Tags: c#, angular, post, asp.net-web-api2

I'm posting some formData from my Angular 5 app to my Web API. Here's the typescript code:

```
public postFormData() {
    const form = $('#customListForm')[0];
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('tenant', form[0].value);
    formData.append('username', form[1].value);
    formData.append('password', form[2].value);

    formData.append('CL_title', form[3].value);
    formData.append('CL_description', form[4].value);
    formData.append('CL_contentType', form[5].value);
    formData.append('CL_template', form[6].value);

    // const json = JSON.stringify(formData);

    this.http.post(this.apiURL, formData, this.httpOptions).catch(this.errorHandler).subscribe(res => this.formPosted(res));
    // this.http.get(this.apiURL).catch(this.errorHandler).subscribe(res => this.formPosted(res));
}
```

Here's my httpOptions:

```
private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    })
  };
```

I've tried various content types like application/json, or multipart/form-data but none work too.

Here's my Controller Post Action:

```
// POST api/customlist
    [HttpPost]
    public System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Post(CustomList data)
    {
        var test = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var testje = data;

        return Ok("POST all good");
    }
```

Here you can see my CustomList custom object:

```
public class CustomList
{
    public CustomList()
    {

    }

    public string Tenant { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string CL_title { get; set; }
    public string CL_description { get; set; }
    public string CL_contentType { get; set; }
    public string CL_template { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see it contains the same fields as my formData & has a default/empty constructor.

No matter what I try, I always get my "data" to be null... Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `FormData` instead of a properly typed model?

Comment: Well I found that as an example online, It used to work previously with a .NET Core 2 Web API, but I guess now it doesn't... So what are you suggesting, to make a model CustomList in my front-end, with the correct values, then pass that in my POST?

Comment: Think you need `[FromBody]` attribute on your POST

Comment: Can you show what Chrome says is the request body?

Comment: With what configuration? what contenttype and what Post(parameters)?